# jQuery UI select menu changes label for attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu

Am using  `jQuery selectmenu`,which is changing for attribute of the label corresponding to the `Select` element.
Ex:
Am applying select menu like this

```
$('#ATTRIBUTE_4').selectmenu();
```

Its getting applied and my element turns like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="ATTRIBUTE_4-button">Label</label>
            <span style="float:right;margin-right:15px;">:</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="attribute_4" id="ATTRIBUTE_4" display: none;">
                <option value="Open">Open</option>
                <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
            </select>
            <span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
                tabindex="0" id="ATTRIBUTE_4-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="ATTRIBUTE_4-menu" aria-haspopup="true" 
                aria-activedescendant="ui-id-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" 
                aria-disabled="false" style="width: 165px;">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                <span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Open</span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this its changing label for attribute also.
`<label for="ATTRIBUTE_4-button">Label</label>`
I can change to `<label for="ATTRIBUTE_4">Label</label>` using jQuery.But is there any way that we can do not to change this for attribute while applying selectmenu() method?

Comment: What does your HTML look like before you initialize the selectmenu?

Comment: html looks like this before applying select menu..<label for="ATTRIBUTE_4">Label</label>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation says,

> The select menu is based on a native select element, which is hidden
>   from view and replaced with a custom-styled select button.

As jQuery creates button based select with `id="ATTRIBUTE_4-button"` and hides your original one, therefore it changes for attribute of label to `for="ATTRIBUTE_4-button"` as to represent the newly created select button.
Also, it is complimentary to have unique ids for controls on the page.

**But is there any way that we can do not to change this for attribute while applying selectmenu() method?**

There is not any customization option to control this thing, however you have to write your custom logic if you have severe necessity to retain these attributes.